# Unable to get a Text provider, abort

Tags: python, kivy

I installed kivy and pygame to python and tried to run this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="fcguh")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

It displayed an error message saying "No module named 'kivy'".

Then I tried to find the solutions on the Internet and did something I can't recall and the error message became like this:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\dekmeymey\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-06-12_4.txt 
[INFO   ] [Kivy      ] v1.11.0 
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py" 
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe" [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded 
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored) 
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. 
Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
            fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
            from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

        pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
            fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
            from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

I tried installing kivy again in case if I missed anything but nothing changes. Can anybody help? I have a school project to complete.

Edit: Before I was able to install my kivy, my pip doesn't work either. I tried countless ways on the Internet for the solution, but I just uninstalled and reinstalled back python to get it to work.

I found the answer!!

I copied this into the command prompt

```
bitsadmin /transfer "GetBatch" "https://git.io/vDDjn" "%cd%\python\kivy.bat"
cd python
```

and then searched kivy in C:. After that, I copied my pyhton file and put it into the kivy folder. Run it, and it worked!!

Comment: Hi. Is this related to Blender?

Comment: Hi. No. It's related to python

Comment: Wait I just realized that the logo above is the Blender logo. How do I change?

Comment: Sorry wrong place

Comment: @daunfifi123c456b: Install PIL (Pillow): `python -m pip install pillow`. Have you installed all the dependencies?

Comment: I downloaded it, but nothing changes. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that directory to the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../kivy')
```

Maybe put this into a module if you are using it a lot.

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing: when I edited your question (*import*s at the beginning), it wouldn't let me save the edit because of the title :"*Kivy not working*" (it had to be changed). I find that more than *OK*, since *Kivy* **is** working, the problem is on your side. What I don't understand is: why that title was allowed in the first place.

The error stands out:

> ```
> pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
> ```

This is quite common. *Pillow* (formerly known as *PIL*), is one of *Kivy*'s dependencies.

Check [[Kivy]: Installation on Windows - Installing the kivy stable release](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installing-the-kivy-stable-release), for more details, paying attention to the `python -m pip install ...` steps. 
One of them will install *Pillow* - or if that doesn't happen (although it shouldn't), install it manually: `python -m pip install pillow` (might apply to other packages as well).

Comment: I accidentally posted this question on stack exchange for Blender and was migrated here. I posted a copy of this question with a different title before it was migrated.

Comment: I did it, twice in fact, didn't work.